# Consider only specific columns while doing a minus in sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a 'device' table with columns - id, group, function, date. Function can have two values - 'print', 'copy' and 'scan'. Group can have values - A, B, C....
I want to run the query select distinct id, group, date from device where function = 'print' minus (select id, group, date where function in ('copy', 'scan') order by date;

Here I want a list of device IDs for devices that are only used for printing for a particular group.
If we have this device table:

device:

```
id     group   function    date             
  1      a       print       26-06-20              
  1      a       scan        27-06-20                  
  2      a       print       28-06-20              
  2      b       scan        29-06-20           
  3      a       print       30-06-20
```

In this case I want the result to be {(2, a, 28-06-20), (3, a, 30-06-20)}
Here I don't want device_id 1 as it has both the values 'print' and scan for the same group. I only want those device IDs that do not have values other than print for the same group.
Here device id also has both the values - 'print' and 'scan' but they are for different groups. Print is for group a and scan is for group b. So for device id - 2 and group - 'a' we only have print. So I want to have device_id in my list of devices.
For device id - '3' has only print values in the function table so I also want it to be in my list.

The issue I'm facing is that the query is not working as expected because the dates are not same for print and scan for device ids, even if they belong to the same group. So when I try to do a minus' I also get those device IDs that have both the values'print' and 'scan' for the same group because minus did not happen due to date mismatch. I want to know how I can ignore the date while doing a minus in the query?

Query I'm using - Select distinct id, group, date from device where function = 'print' minus (select id, group, date where function in ('copy', 'scan') order by date;

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Once you've figured out which RDBMS you're using, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select distinct workstation_id, type, usage_date from device where type = 
'print' and id not in (select id from device group by id having count(1) > 1 );
```

You can also use below query,

```
select distinct workstation_id, type, usage_date from device where type = 
'print' and id not in (select id from
(select id, count(1) from group by id having count(1) > 1) qry);
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please answer on the basis of my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select distinct workstation_id, type, usage_date 
  from device d
 where d.type = 'print' 
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from device dd 
                    where dd.workstation_id = d.workstation_id 
                      and dd.group = d.group 
                      and dd.type = 'scan');
```

Recommendation: never use `NOT IN`

Comment: "Never"? Why not?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please answer on the basis of my updated question?

Comment: `NOT IN` will not work properly when there is null in it. The Answer is updated according to the updated requirement. Please check now!!

Comment: @Tejash Can you check the question now? I have changed it slightly...so this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I think you need 2 and 3 in output. Above answer will work.

Comment: @Littlefoot, With not in, Oracle compares the column to all values in the subquery. If any of the values are null the whole expression will be null, so return nothing. As Null is neither equal to nor not equal to anything!

Comment: That's correct, @Tejash. But that's not a reason for **never** using it. If you said "beware of NULL values" or something like that, it would make more sense. "Never" is perhaps too strong word.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the ids where type!='print';

```
select distinct workstation_id, type, usage_date from device 
where type = 'print' and workstation_id not in (select workstation_id from device where type != 'print');
```

After question update

```
select distinct id, group, date from device d1 
    where function = 'print' and not exists (select 1 from device d1 
where 
function != 'print' and d1.id=d2.id and d1.group=d2.group);
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please answer on the basis of my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

> A list of device IDs for devices that are only used for printing for a particular group.

```
-- Populate table with sample data
WITH device AS (
SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS "group", 'print' AS function, TO_DATE('2020-06-26','YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date" FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS "group", 'scan' AS function, TO_DATE('2020-06-27','YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date" FROM DUAL UNION                  
SELECT 2 AS id, 'a' AS "group", 'print' AS function, TO_DATE('2020-06-28','YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date" FROM DUAL UNION              
SELECT 2 AS id, 'b' AS "group", 'scan' AS function, TO_DATE('2020-06-29','YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date" FROM DUAL UNION           
SELECT 3 AS id, 'a' AS "group", 'print' AS function, TO_DATE('2020-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD') AS "date" FROM DUAL  
)
-- Query the sample data
SELECT
    printing_device.* 
FROM device printing_device
LEFT JOIN device non_printing_device
    ON printing_device.ID = non_printing_device.ID 
    AND printing_device."group" = non_printing_device."group"
    AND non_printing_device.FUNCTION != 'print'
WHERE 
printing_device.FUNCTION='print' 
AND non_printing_device.id IS null;
```

Results:

```
ID  group   FUNCTION    date(YYYY-MM-DD)
2   a       print       2020-06-28
3   a       print       2020-06-30
```

I hope your sample data uses made up example column names. Using SQL keywords like GROUP or DATE as column names causes syntax errors when writing queries. Everyone who attempts to test an answer to this question must change the column names or use identifiers with double quotes.